# Is there a formal proof that Autoencoders perform non-linear PCA?

Tags: neural-networks, pca, autoencoders

I have seen this statement in various blog posts, papers etc., and the claim is intuitive for me, however I had a hard time finding a paper with the actual proof for that.

I guess one could view that as a case of Kernel PCA, but it is not obvious to me that each Neural Network model will automatically fulfill requirements for a kernel function.
Besides there are [papers](https://aiche.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/aic.690370209) which came out before the Kernel PCA paper.
I would also assume that one needs to modify the training algorithm to learn the actual principal components.

Is there a classic work that I have simply overlooked?

Answer (score 7):

There is not a formal proof because the assertion is false: autoencoders do not perform non-linear PCA.

PCA is defined as a (reversible) linear transformation into a space where variables are now orthogonal that captures maximal variance.
Autoencoders do not do that in general.

Linear autoencoders with $k$-dimensional bottlenecks will often *converge* to the space spanned by the $k$ first principal components.
Notice, however, that the orthogonal part is forsaken.

Non-linear PCA  is mostly Kernel PCA.
This entails a specific space: one defined by the kernel of choice.
Non-linear autoencoders, most often (I'm sure there are exceptions) do not employ kernels, instead modelling a local space directly.
So, in essence, they are not performing non-linear PCA, just non-linear dimension reduction.

Comment: It's not the space that is orthogonal, it's the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't fully understand one thing though - what does the 'local space' modeled by (non-linear) AEs correspond to in non-linear PCA? Is that the space spanned by the components uncovered by PCA?